# How to execute the Node js code in live sever or website

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie to node js. Learning  through the udemy and youtube. Every time my write a code or create a server i need to use command prompt to execute the code.

I want to to understand how this nodejs code will automatically executed in live website or live server and where exactly we need to put this code.

It would be great if some can help me on this query.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this on server is use pm2 to manage your application.
1.deploy code on server
2.use pm2 to start server if code is updated then need to restart server using pm2

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/

Comment: PM2 is by far the best choice here. The answer above will not be persistent after you close the shell session, nor a reboot. You can setup PM2 to automatically restart all processes, see http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general question. You can deploy your application to cloud services of Amazon, Google or Microsoft. Or you can use Heroku service which is easy to use but, a bit more expensive than other choices.

Generally the best way to deploy your application to any service or cloud is to use their packages or cli's. For example, for aws you can use elastic beanstalk cli. It has an `eb deploy` method which makes pretty easy the things. For heroku, you can use its package. What you need to is simply, commit your changes and add the heroku repo as a remote via git. Then push the code to your heroku server.

Once the application is deployed, in most cases `npm start` command runs on servers. So you need to configure your package.json like below:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}
```

If you are not familiar with any cloud server, I would suggest you go with Heroku at first. It is simple and has lots of tutorials out there. And the free tier will be enough for you to understand how things work in a real server.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a package to see the changes directly without starting the server from command propt, you can use the package `nodemon`. If you start your app with `node app.js`, you start it with `nodemon app.js`. After starting like this, for every changes you make, the server will restart automatically. But this for development purposes, not for production. You should not change the code in production always.

Comment: Hi Burak Gavas, Thank you for your answer. Iam running a basic website and using godaddy domain and webhosting. how  i need to proceed with node js in that. please clarify this. I got struct on this nodejs from last on week.

Comment: Personally, I didn't use GoDaddy for web hosting. I don't know how to do it with GoDaddy. But, as I said, I suggest you try heroku. It is so easy to use. You can use this link [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs]. It takes only three steps to deploy a basic application to server.